Calico in K8S environment not creating routes for serviceSubnet IPs
I'm experimenting with setting up my own K8S cluster with a full spread of nodes - 3 control plane nodes, 3 worker nodes and 2 storage nodes (using rook-ceph to handle actual storage), using calico for CNI routing.
During my attempts and experimentation I learned that it was contraindicated to have the serviceSubnet and podSubnet IP ranges overlap, so in my latest attempt they are on separate networks:
networking:
  dnsDomain: company-k8s.local
  serviceSubnet: 10.221.0.0/16
  podSubnet: 10.222.0.0/16

Everything works and after a lot of hassle I got almost everything to work; for some reason despite ceph installing correctly I couldn't get it to actually respond to PVCs:
Name:          my-bucket-pvc
Namespace:     default
StorageClass:  ceph-bucket
Status:        Pending
Volume:        
Labels:        <none>
Annotations:   volume.beta.kubernetes.io/storage-provisioner: rook-ceph.ceph.rook.io/bucket
               volume.kubernetes.io/storage-provisioner: rook-ceph.ceph.rook.io/bucket
Finalizers:    [kubernetes.io/pvc-protection]
Capacity:      
Access Modes:  
VolumeMode:    Filesystem
Used By:       <none>
Events:
  Type    Reason                Age                   From                         Message
  ----    ------                ----                  ----                         -------
  Normal  ExternalProvisioning  81s (x56827 over 9d)  persistentvolume-controller  Waiting for a volume to be created either by the external provisioner 'rook-ceph.ceph.rook.io/bucket' or manually by the system administrator. If volume creation is delayed, please verify that the provisioner is running and correctly registered.

When I shelled into one of the provisioner containers to troubleshoot I discovered that it couldn't reach its controller components to negotiate the storage.
A bit more investigation led me to discover that while Calico had no problems creating routes in the podSubnet range, it for some reason was not creating routes at all for IPs in the serviceSubnet range.
Clearly I missed something, probably something very basic, but I don't have the experience yet to figure out what. If anyone has any pointers, I'd be glad to hear them.
(Note: I am not wedded to the use of calico specifically for CNI; it's just the first hit that came up that didn't boil down to "route everything to everything" and I do want at least some pretense at isolation and access control; if there's an alternative that'll work better I'll happily consider it)
